# Google Chrome extension to move a tab to another Chrome window with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: chrome

I have a multi-monitor setup and I often have two or three monitors with a maximized Google Chrome window on it. I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can move a tab to another Chrome window with a keyboard shortcut. (I don't want to have to use the [mouse](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95622?hl=en))

Ideally the extension would take into account the position of the windows, and would provide a shortcut to move the tab to the left/right/up/down Google Chrome window if there is any located there.

If OS-dependent, I would prefer that it is Windows 7 compatible.